# Rsync in docker duplicating files to /root for cron job

Tags: docker

I am trying to create an rsync job that runs on a cron tab in a docker container based off
https://github.com/cheyer/docker-cron
from a mounted volume, to a remote server
ex

```
rsync -a --no-i-r --partial --inplace --info=COPY2,DEL2,NAME,BACKUP2,REMOVE2,SKIP2 -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa" /src/* server@192.168.100.100:/filepath --log-file=/logs/cron.log  >> /logs/cron.log 2>&1
```

and the docker compose file looks something like

```
      volumes:
          - /mnt/filepath/:/src
```

and when i run rsync, it does actually copy to the target server
but when i run from a cron job, it duplicates every file into
/root/
on the docker container, which quickly fills up the host's disk

any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like running from a cron job has different environment variables
I was trying to pass in the destination as one, so it would default to nothing

Leaving the question up just in case someone runs into the same issue